# Solving system of equations in many variables but only plotting 2 variables

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm trying to do the following: I have a system of (polynomial) equations in several real variables, of the form $f_i(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_j) = 0$. I want to plot only the $(x_1, x_2)$ coordinates of the solutions of those equations in the $x, y$ plane. In order words, find solutions for the equations, and then project those vectors onto the first 2 coordinates.

I don't know the correct Mathematica functions or syntax to use for this, some basic examples would be appreciated.

Something with numerical solutions and plotting a lot of points in the plane would also work (maybe even preferable).

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided a simple example of your system. For example, `Reduce[{3*x1+2*x2-x3==0,-4*x1+x2-3*x3==0},{x1,x2}]` returns `x1==(-5*x3)/11 && x2==(13*x3)/11`

Comment: Please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

- `ParametricRegin`  2 equations and 4 variables.

```
Clear[polys,reg];
polys = {3*x1 + 2*x2*x1 - x3^2 + x1*x4, -4*x1^2 + x2*x3 - 3*x3*x1 + 
    x2*x4};
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x1, x2}, polys == 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}];
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001], 
 FrameLabel -> {"x1", "x2"}]
```

[image]

- `ParametricRegion` 3 equations and 4 variables.

```
Clear[polys, reg];
polys = {3*x1 + 2*x2*x1 - x3^2 + x1*x4, -4*x1^2 + x2*x3 - 3*x3*x1 + 
    x2*x4, x2*x3 - x4};
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x1, x2}, polys == 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}];
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001], 
 FrameLabel -> {"x1", "x2"}]
```

[image]

- `ParametricRegion` 2 equations adnd 3 variables.

```
Clear[polys,reg];
polys = {3*x1 + 2*x2*x1 - x3^2, -4*x1^2 + x2*x3 - 3*x3*x1};
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x1, x2}, polys == 0}, {x1, x2, x3}];
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001], 
 FrameLabel -> {"x1", "x2"}]
```

[image]

- `Resolve` 2 equations and 3 variables.

```
Clear[polys];
polys = {3*x1 + 2*x2*x1 - x3^2, -4*x1^2 + x2*x3 - 3*x3*x1};
Resolve[Exists[{x3}, polys == 0], Reals]
```

> `(x1 == 0 && 3 x1 - x2 != 0) || (x1 == 0 &&  x2 == 0) || (3 x1 - x2 !=  0 && -27 x1^2 + 16 x1^3 + 18 x1 x2 - 18 x1^2 x2 - 3 x2^2 +  12 x1 x2^2 - 2 x2^3 == 0)`

- `Resolve` 2 equations and  4 variables.

```
Clear[polys, result];
polys = {3*x1 + 2*x2*x1 - x3^2 + x1*x4, -4*x1^2 + x2*x3 - 3*x3*x1 + 
    x2*x4};
result = Resolve[Exists[{x3, x4}, polys == 0], Reals]
RegionPlot[result, {x1, -5, 5}, {x2, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

- `Eliminate` 2 equations and 3 variables.( for 4 variables seems does not work)

```
Clear[polys];
polys = {3*x1 + 2*x2*x1 - x3^2, -4*x1^2 + x2*x3 - 3*x3*x1};
ContourPlot[
 Eliminate[polys == 0, {x3}] // Evaluate, {x1, -5, 5}, {x2, -5, 5}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80]
```

[image]